# Deploying lambda in private subnet. Error creating Lambda Function (1): ValidationException status code: 400, request id

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I am trying to deploy nodejs lambda zip file into a private subnet custom vpc using terraform.
The terraform plan works fine. But throws errors while applying the changes. The roles get created but terraform lambda doesn't deploy and errors out in a minute. Error is:
"error creating Lambda Function (1): ValidationException: status code: 400, request id..."
This lambda will be invoked by cloud watch-event.

Anything to do with VPC roles?

```
//calling module
module "lambda" {

  providers = {
    aws.programmatic = aws.programmatic

  }
  
  source                         = "../modules/lambda"
  description                    = var.description
  filename                       = "${path.module}/filename.zip}"
  function_name                  = "rfcsyncfunc" 
  handler                        = "index.handler"
  memory_size                    = 512
  publish                        = false
  reserved_concurrent_executions = 20
  runtime                        = "nodejs14.x"
  source_code_hash               =  filebase64sha256(var.filename)
  timeout                        = 90
  
    vpc_config = {
    security_group_ids = ["sg-123456789"]  
    subnet_ids         = ["xx.xx.xxx.xxx/27","xx.xx.xx.xx/27"]  //["subnet-1", "subnet-2"]
  }

  environment = {
    variables = {
      TEST1API_URL  = "https://example.com/test.asmx"
      TEST2API_URL  = "https://example.com/test/staging/test2.asmx"
     
    }
  }


}
```

---

```
//lambda module
provider aws {
  alias = "programmatic"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  description = var.description
  dynamic "environment" {
    for_each = length(var.environment) < 1 ? [] : [var.environment]
    content {
      variables = environment.value.variables
    }
  }
  filename                       = var.s3_bucket == "" ? var.filename : null
  function_name                  = var.function_name
  handler                        = var.handler
  memory_size                    = var.memory_size
  publish                        = var.publish
  reserved_concurrent_executions = var.reserved_concurrent_executions
  role                           = aws_iam_role.lambda.arn
  runtime                        = var.runtime
  source_code_hash               = var.source_code_hash
  tags                           = var.tags
  timeout                        = var.timeout

  dynamic "vpc_config" {
    for_each = length(var.vpc_config) < 1 ? [] : [var.vpc_config]
    content {
      security_group_ids = vpc_config.value.security_group_ids
      subnet_ids         = vpc_config.value.subnet_ids
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda" {
  name               = "${var.function_name}-lambdarole"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy.json
  permissions_boundary = var.permissions_boundary
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "cloudwatch_logs" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "vpc_eniattachment" {
  count = length(var.vpc_config) < 1 ? 0 : 1
  role  = aws_iam_role.lambda.name  
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaENIManagementAccess"
}

/*
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "vpc_attachment" {
  count = length(var.vpc_config) < 1 ? 0 : 1
  role  = aws_iam_role.lambda.name  
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
}
*/
```

```
module/clouwatchevent

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "cloudwatch" {
  count         = var.enable ? 1 : 0
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = var.lambda_function_arn
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.lambda[count.index].arn
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "lambda" {
  count               = var.enable ? 1 : 0
  description         = var.description
  event_pattern       = var.event_pattern
  is_enabled          = var.is_enabled
  name                = var.name
  name_prefix         = var.name_prefix
  schedule_expression = var.schedule_expression
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "lambda" {
  count = var.enable ? 1 : 0
  rule  = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.lambda[count.index].name
  arn   = var.lambda_function_arn
}
```

Comment: The issue is only with private subnet? Does it deploy in public subnet?

Comment: @john by default all are subnets are attached to igw. so technically all are public. just that they are not exposed.

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean? A subnet is either public or private. There is no other type.

Comment: yeah. You are right. just tht they are not exposed from the firewall side, no NAT.  The above error is not hinting at the underlying cause. Also, terraform debug not showing any detail logs. do you think issue is related to if its is private or public?

Comment: What about lambda invocation permissions for cloudwatch events?

Comment: @marcin.yeah i have a separate cloud watch event resource module that has permission for lambda executions. i pass the lambda arn to that module

Comment: @CharlesDeeZee What's the file size of your Lambda (ZIP?) file you're uploading? Direct uploads to Lambda have a 50MB limit, I believe, so if it's larger then that it could be the issue. Also, why is your `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.vpc_attachment` resource commented out?

Comment: @Jordan . thanks for your responses. Solved the issue. I was passing subnet cidr blocks instead of subnet-id's . it works now.

Comment: It's funny because I had this same error message happen to me yesterday. In my case, it was trying to create a Lambda with a period in the name, which apparently is not OK. Zero information in the error message, and for some reason the error wasn't showing in CloudTrail either. AWS needs to improve its validation error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Just sharing my case and hopefully saves someone else's time. I removed the hyphen from the environment variable key name and it works. From `KEY-NAME` to `KEY_NAME`. I see some people have also solved by removing characters such as dots in the function name. `ValidationException` error message is pretty vague.